# Building a multidimensional array on the fly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do you build a multidimensional array on the fly?

I know this is an open ended question, but I am having a hell of a time with it.

What I have is the possibility of the a piece of an array needing to cause the array to add another child.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [parentID] => 0
        [component] => 23941/01  
        [decoration] =>          
        [hasChild] => T
        [proccessed] => T
        [cmp0] => Array
            (
                [parentID] => 0
                [component] => COLC01    
                [decoration] =>          
                [hasChild] => F
                [proccessed] => T
            )

        [cmp1] => Array
            (
                [parentID] => 0
                [component] => PPH   
                [decoration] =>          
                [hasChild] => F
                [proccessed] => T
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [parentID] => 1
        [component] => 23930/20SB
        [decoration] =>          
        [hasChild] => T
        [proccessed] => T
        [cmp0] => Array
            (
                [parentID] => 1
                [component] => 23930/20  
                [decoration] =>          
                [hasChild] => T
                [proccessed] => F
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [parentID] => 2
        [component] => SC070400SB
        [decoration] =>          
        [hasChild] => T
        [proccessed] => T
        [cmp0] => Array
            (
                [parentID] => 2
                [component] => SC070400  
                [decoration] =>          
                [hasChild] => F
                [proccessed] => T
            )

    ))
```

The outer arrays [0,1,2] I generated with simple array pushes.  When I start to traverse the array to get to the lower levels, I am having a problem getting more than a layer deep.

**Here is my major question**:  How do I dynamically add elements to the array, while still being able to check for a key value to see if I should go deeper?  Both the processed and hasChild flags tell me I can go deeper, but isset and array_key_exists doesn't seem to work on newly added elements.  In fact when I print the array to the screen it doesn't even show any elements like [cmp0]...

I am not sure how much my code is going to help, but I'll lay it out here for browsing.

```
function explodeBOM(&$BOMArray,$library,$sonar){        
    $saveKey = '';
    $childCounter = 0;
    $childKey = '';
    foreach($BOMArray as &$bomLine){  
        $childKey = 'cmp' . (string)$childCounter;
        while(array_key_exists($childKey,$bomLine)){                
            explodeBOM($bomLine[$childKey],$library,$sonar);
        }
        if($bomLine['proccessed'] == "F"){
             $saveKey = $bomLine['parentID'];
             $bomItems = getBOM($bomLine['component'],$bomLine['decoration'],$library,$sonar);
             foreach($bomItems as $newBomLine){
                 $itemMasterInfo = getItemMasterInfo($newBomLine['BMCMP#'],$newBomLine['BMCMD#'],$library,$sonar);
                 if($itemMasterInfo['ITPRTC'] != 'P' AND $itemMasterInfo['ITPRTC'] != 'C'){            
                    // add it to the array                        
                    $componetArray = array();
                    $componetArray['parentID'] = $saveKey;
                    $componetArray['component'] = $newBomLine['BMCMP#'];
                    $componetArray['decoration'] = $newBomLine['BMCMD#'];
                    $componetArray['hasChild'] = parentOrChildBOM($newBomLine['BMCMP#'],$newBomLine['BMCMD#'],$library,$sonar);
                    if ($componetArray['hasChild'] == 'F'){
                        $componetArray['proccessed'] = 'T';                        
                    }else{
                        $componetArray['proccessed'] = 'F';                    
                    }                        
                    //array_push($bomLine,$componetArray);
                    $childKey = 'cmp' . (string)$childCounter;
                    $childCounter++;
                    $bomLine[$childKey] = $componetArray;
                    $bomLine['proccessed'] = 'T';

                    reset($BOMArray);
                 }
             }
             $childCounter = 0;
         } 
     }            
}
```

Comment: Why add the children under the parent?  If they all have a unique ID just have one flat array like a DB table.  You can then foreach and get all items with a certain parentID.

Comment: I would actually like to keep the relationships between the parents and children. The end result will need them.